# Замена галереи при помощи ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Проблема заключается в следующем:
я делаю интернет магазин и на странице товара есть галерея в которой товар сфотографирован с разных ракурсов все фотографии хранятся в базе, а так же есть расцветка товара т.е одна вещь в разных цветах. Я хочу сделать следующее по нажатию на расцветку товара менялась и галерея товара без обновления страницы.

```
<div class="gallery-sample">
    <div class="left-image-zone">
        <? foreach ($imageList as $image) : // table angle?>
            <? if ($image['name_img'] == $product['name_img']):?>
                <img class = 'cloudzoom-gallery' src = "<? echo $image['path'] . $image['name'];?>"
                    data-cloudzoom =
                    "useZoom: '.cloudzoom',
                    image: '<? echo $image['path'] . $image['name'];?>',
                    zoomImage: '<? echo $image['path'] . $image['name'];?>' " >
            <? endif;?>
        <? endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <div id="fanc" class="main-image">
        <img class = "cloudzoom" src = "<?echo $product['path'] . $product['name_img'];?>"
            data-cloudzoom =
            "zoomImage: '<?echo $product['path'] . $product['name_img'];?>',
            zoomSizeMode: 'image'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Меняй, разрешаю) Код хоть приведите этой галереи. Что это за галерея? какой-то фреймворк её делает? плагинчик? что-то самописное? Побольше информации немного бы.

Comment: Сама галерея выводится через плагин http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pywhgddy/ скрипт галереи

Comment: @АзиретКадыкеев зачем размещать php код на jsfiddle? Есть кнопка "правка" - вот и добавляйте код в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Схема примерно следующая - у вас смена галереи должна будет производиться по нажатию на ссылку с определенным классом (чтобы избежать перехода - в конце события добавляйте `return: false;`). Отправляете запрос функцией `$.ajax()` в которой отправляете запрос на указанную в `href` страницу, а в `success:` прописываете функцию, которая заменит полученным кодом сам блок галереи.

В backend'е же вы делаете одним из 2-х способов:

1) Делаете отдельный php файл который будет в зависимости от переданных ему параметров выводить код ТОЛЬКО ГАЛЕРЕИ для нужного товара. Этот способ менее трудозатратный.

2) В шаблоне вывода товара добавляете проверку - если страница получена методом `XMLHttpRequest` - то выводите только галерею, если нет - то выводите страницу как обычно.

Ну и есть еще небольшой нюанс - все события, прописанные в стиле `$('.myclass').click(function(){})` не будут работать на блоках вставленных ajax'om, так как события навешиваются при загрузке страницы, а здесь навешиваете на конкретный класс. Избежать довольно просто - нужно вызывать как `$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(){})`

Comment: Я вас понял, но проблема заключается в том что я ваобще не знаю и ни разу не пользовался ajax и читая документацию не могу её понять если вам не трудно можете примерно накидать ajax кода. Спасибо!

Comment: @АзиретКадыкеев я конечно могу дать пример своего кода, но вы оттуда мало что поймете [есть описание](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) - там же есть и примеры, вот его и читайте. Пробуйте. А уже с возникающими запросами - создавайте здесь конкретные вопросы.

Comment: @АзиретКадыкеев причем метод написания примерно такой - сперва попробуйте просто какую-то страницу запросить ajax'ом. Затем уже пробуйте вывести то что на этой странице методом alert(),   затем попытайтесь передать какой-то параметр и вывести его, затем пытайтесь удалить блок галереи и вместо него вставить то что выводили alеrt'ом, потом уже делайте чтобы выводилось не что-то, а галерея, а уже потом делайте чтоб галерея выводилась в зависимости от переданного параметра.